# What does "applicative" mean?

Tags: haskell

When reading stuff on Haskell, I sometimes come across the adjective "applicative", but I have not been able to find a sufficiently clear definition of this *adjective* (as opposed to, say, Haskell's `Applicative` class).  I would like to learn to recognize a piece of code/algorithm/data structure, etc. that is "applicative", just like I can recognize one that is "recursive".  Some contrasting examples of "applicative" vs. whatever the term intends to draw a distinction from (which I hope is something more meaningful in its own right than "non-applicative") would be much appreciated.

Edit: for example, why was the word "applicative" chosen to name the class, and not some other name?  What is it about this class that makes the name `Applicative` such a good fit for it (even at the price of its obscurity)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a page using this terminology?

Comment: it used to be "idioms"; a friend (Adam Megacz) who knows more says he preferred "idioms" to "applicative functor" (I think I recall him saying "it's not really a functor").

Comment: Any `Applicative` is also a `Functor`... it's only for lack of foresight that we don't have `class Functor a => Applicative a`.

Comment: @pelotom: Er... we do. It's `Monad` that escapes the hierarchy.

Comment: @ehird: oops, right you are. I guess my Haskell is a little rusty :) But I don't understand in what sense gatoatigrado's friend meant "it's not really a functor". What's not really a functor? All lawful `Applicative` instances are functors...

Answer (score 23):

It's not clear what "applicative" is being used to mean without knowing the context.

If it's truly not referring to applicative functors (i.e. `Applicative`), then it's probably referring to the form of application itself: `f a b c` is an *applicative* form, and this is where applicative functors get their name from: `f <$> a <*> b <*> c` is analogous. (Indeed, [idiom brackets](http://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/~conor/pub/she/idiom.html) take this connection further, by letting you write it as `(| f a b c |)`.)

Similarly, "applicative languages" can be contrasted with languages that are not primarily based on the application of function to argument (usually in prefix form); concatenative ("stack based") languages aren't applicative, for instance.

To answer the question of why applicative functors are called what they are in depth, I recommend reading
[*Applicative programming with effects*](http://strictlypositive.org/IdiomLite.pdf); the basic idea is that a lot of situations call for something like "enhanced application": applying pure functions within some effectful context. Compare these definitions of `map` and `mapM`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM _ [] = return []
mapM f (x:xs) = do
  x' <- f x
  xs' <- mapM f xs
  return (x' : xs')
```

with `mapA` (usually called [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Traversable.html#v%3atraverse)):

```
mapA :: (Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
mapA _ [] = pure []
mapA f (x:xs) = (:) <$> f x <*> mapA f xs
```

As you can see, `mapA` is much more concise, and more obviously related to `map` (even more so if you use the prefix form of `(:)` in `map` too). Indeed, using the applicative functor notation even when you have a full `Monad` is common in Haskell, since it's often much more clear.

Looking at the definition helps, too:

```
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> f a
  (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Compare the type of `(<*>)` to the type of application: `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`. What `Applicative` offers is a generalised "lifted" form of application, and code using it is written in an *applicative* style.

More formally, as mentioned in the paper and pointed out by ertes, `Applicative` is a generalisation of the [SK combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus); `pure` is a generalisation of `K :: a -> (r -> a)` (aka `const`), and `(<*>)` is a generalisation of `S :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)`. The `r -> a` part is simply generalised to `f a`; the original types are obtained with the `Applicative` instance for `((->) r)`.

As a practical matter, `pure` also allows you to write applicative expressions in a more uniform manner: `pure f <*> effectful <*> pure x <*> effectful` as opposed to `(\a b -> f a x b) <$> effectful <*> effectful`.

Answer (score 16):

On a more fundamental level one could say that "applicative" means working in some form of the SK calculus.  This is also what the `Applicative` class is about.  It gives you the combinators `pure` (a generalization of K) and `<*>` (a generalization of S).

Your code is applicative when it is expressed in such a style.  For example the code

```
liftA2 (+) sin cos
```

is an applicative expression of

```
\x -> sin x + cos x
```

Of course in Haskell the `Applicative` class is the main construct for programming in an applicative style, but even in a monadic or arrowic context you can write applicatively:

```
return (+) `ap` sin `ap` cos

arr (uncurry (+)) . (sin &&& cos)
```

Whether the last piece of code is applicative is controversial though, because one might argue that applicative style needs currying to make sense.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the term "applicative" is rooted in combinatory logic.

Comment: Indeed, *Applicative programming with effects* notes this directly: "This class generalises S and K from threading an environment to threading an effect in general."